# Converting an SQL Statement into R Code Without SQLDF

Tags: sql, r, loops, sqldf

I'm a new-ish programmer in R and I'm having a bit of an issue with some SQL code.

What I want to do is to convert this operation to base R code. I know it's quite complicated and I tried using merge but I didn't really manage to get anywhere.

```
    Censored <- sqldf("SELECT Censored1.ModelYearID, Censored1.InServiceDate,      Censored1.Censored, Censored1.VIN
FROM Censored1 LEFT JOIN Claims ON Censored1.VIN = Claims.VIN
GROUP BY Censored1.ModelYearID, Censored1.InServiceDate, Censored1.Censored, Censored1.VIN, Claims.VIN
HAVING (((Claims.VIN) Is Null))")
```

The reason I want to do this is because I have ~1600 different Claims tables in a data frame list (df_listl) which are named like this:

LabourOperation.ModelYearID e.g. Q123456.1997, Q234567.1998

and I need to run this query for every one of these tables, putting each of the comparable censored tables in the same kind of list.

If anyone could help me with this, that would be great. It's a bit complicated and I'm really struggling as I've only just learnt that you can put data frames in lists!

I was thinking that lapply might be a good way to go but I'm not very good with functions yet.

Thank you in advance :D

Comment: I guess it would help if you could provide a sample of your data (it doesn't have to be neither long nor exact to your actual dataset; just the basic concept of what you have) and the output you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm confused as to why you are joining on VIN an then checking that VIN is null. Are you just trying to extract the unique ModelYearID and InSerrviceDate values in Censored1 that are missing a VIN?